# Cannot find C++ Builder Project in Rad Studio XE 6

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe6, c++builder-xe6

I've just installed Rad Studio XE6.

I am trying to find **C++ Builder Projects**, like in this picture:

[image: screenshot]

But in **my Rad Studio XE6** I do not find C++ Builder Project, I find just **Delphi Projects** and others:

[image: screenshot]

Is there a way to include **C++ Builder Projects** after you installed Rad Studio XE6? Or should I install again a Rad Studio XE6 with Delphi/C++ ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Either:

1. You did not select to install the C++ personality when you installed RAD Studio.
2. If you install both Delphi and C++ personalities, there are 3 shortcuts installed on the Start Menu:

   A. one that loads only the Delphi personality

   B. one that loads only the C++ personality

   C. one that loads the full studio.

   You might be running #A instead of #B or #C.

Comment: Another reason might be that OP owns only a Delphi key and not RAD Studio key. In such case only Delphi part of the rad studio gets installed.

Comment: Indeed, I was running just Delphi instead of running Rad Studio (which loads the full studio). Sorry for delay.